# How would I wrap every 3 divs that my PHP for statement echos out in a wrapper div?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop, echo

I have this code:

```
                $limit = 8;
                for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
                    $title = substr(str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']), 0, 60);
                    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
                    $description = substr(preg_replace('/\<a.*/', '', $feed[$x]['desc']),0 , 120) . " ... "; //$feed[$x]['desc'];
                    $image = preg_replace('/\?w.*/', '', $feed[$x]['image']);
                    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));

                    echo '<div class="blog-item item col-md-4' . $rowOpen . '"><img src="' . $image . '"><div class="blog-item-info"><div class="title"><h3>'. $title . '</h3></div><div class="date">' . $date . '</div><div class="preview"><p>'. $description .'</p></div><a href="' . $link .'"><button class="read-more">Read More</button></a></div></div></div>';

                    /*echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
                    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
                    echo $image;
                    //echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';*/
                }
```

What I want to do is I want every three echos to be wrapped in a

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

So I want it to look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  echo '<div class="blog-item item col-md-4' . $rowOpen . '"><img src="' . $image . '"><div class="blog-item-info"><div class="title"><h3>'. $title . '</h3></div><div class="date">' . $date . '</div><div class="preview"><p>'. $description .'</p></div><a href="' . $link .'"><button class="read-more">Read More</button></a></div></div></div>';
  echo '<div class="blog-item item col-md-4' . $rowOpen . '"><img src="' . $image . '"><div class="blog-item-info"><div class="title"><h3>'. $title . '</h3></div><div class="date">' . $date . '</div><div class="preview"><p>'. $description .'</p></div><a href="' . $link .'"><button class="read-more">Read More</button></a></div></div></div>';
  echo '<div class="blog-item item col-md-4' . $rowOpen . '"><img src="' . $image . '"><div class="blog-item-info"><div class="title"><h3>'. $title . '</h3></div><div class="date">' . $date . '</div><div class="preview"><p>'. $description .'</p></div><a href="' . $link .'"><button class="read-more">Read More</button></a></div></div></div>';
</div><!-- end .row -->
```

I have tried multiple things but I cannot get it to work. What should I do?

Comment: `if ($row % 3 == 0) { start new section }`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the $x modulo 3 is 0, then you need a new row. like this:

```
echo '<div class="row">';

$limit = 8;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = substr(str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']), 0, 60);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = substr(preg_replace('/\<a.*/', '', $feed[$x]['desc']),0 , 120) . " ... ";
    $image = preg_replace('/\?w.*/', '', $feed[$x]['image']);
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));

    // if x is devidable by 3, start a new row
    if($x % 3 == 0 && $x != 0) echo '</div><div class="row">';

    echo '<div class="blog-item item col-md-4' . $rowOpen . '"><img src="' . $image . '"><div class="blog-item-info"><div class="title"><h3>'. $title . '</h3></div><div class="date">' . $date . '</div><div class="preview"><p>'. $description .'</p></div><a href="' . $link .'"><button class="read-more">Read More</button></a></div></div>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

note that you are also closing a div to much in your echo ;)